# Mechanism of alkene dihydroxylation with potassium permanganate

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-oxidation

I have scavenged the internet for different mechanisms for permanganate-mediated alkene oxidation and have found satisfactory mechanisms for oxidative cleavage and dihydroxylation under basic conditions.

However,I found out that $\ce{KMnO4}$ can still dihydroxylate alkenes under acidic conditions, when it is cold and dilute. I am aware that it is not efficient as it is prone to further oxidation, but the mechanism still makes me curious. I know the overall formula:

$$\ce{5alkene + 2MnO4- + 2H2O + 6H+ -> 5diol/glycol + Mn^2+}$$

I can't really understand this, does the manganese oxidise 5 alkenes at the same time? Does it get oxidised 5 times, with a different byproduct for each one? I think that the manganese-bearing compound is $\ce{MnO2}$ at first, then $\ce{Mn^2+}$, but I'm not really sure. If anyone can shed some light on the mechanism, it'll be a great help.

I link below my best attempt at the mechanism. The byproducts are incorrect as it's supposed to be $\ce{MnO2}$ or $\ce{Mn^2+}$ [image: my attempt at the mechanism]

Here are some papers I've found that helped me, maybe someone can get more use out of them than me:

- https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Oxidation-by-permanganate%3A-synthetic-and-aspects-Dash-Patel/fe91f5161ca1ab481ae111f1abc82d37d336f021
- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271107223_Permanganate_Oxidation_mechanisms_of_Alkylarenes

Comment: (1) I'm not sure that the stoichiometry of the reaction is so well-defined; I wouldn't be surprised if there are multiple Mn-containing products in this reaction, so I'm not sure how much we should read into it. (2) I don't know enough about this specific reaction to write an answer (indeed I don't know if the full mechanism has ever been studied), but I would hazard a guess that there are other important redox steps purely involving Mn species (i.e. dis- or comproportionation). You can search the internet for alcohol oxidations with TPAP. The mechanisms of those have been studied.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Yes, I have considered disproportionation (never heard of comproportionation before today though), but couldn't find anything regarding it. I have some papers that I've found that might be helpful, so maybe I'll add them to my post.

Comment: Mechanism has been explored: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01568a042?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=04306b3b0c96ca99fcc28f5d402ff4ca7a1d00b7-1586703493-0-AUkzm2A00AzYtV6yXjjmAusmaudZZINA8gHign3FLbuvVW2_rOOuD-B8FMN2OLgmKV_tlhfpTffaSmLVhW5Z08jbuOfT5sr3SLNZT2UWE8BTmeQuzF5o62AKGt33a0RmwqVYqsIb6hs11454ZypXm0QFdiC_6H5ehOBFvS67jqda80dprtSUPS5mr_CDh3Qh2LtxH_5ivREePqBwqMOmQMqMQTKeq3cRM8hiEZMTkt3g6-jITq76R1g0T00kF7eDGHRkOlcaqygt03TOy3OW5LV59xY6fToiPW_zBNmTPliQCcbzyGxJ92TWw-GNzgb5DQ

Comment: @user55119 that mechanism is for basic conditions, though (article specified a high pH). I studied the mechanism for basic conditions already, since it is similar to that of osmium tetroxide.

Comment: Alkene ---> 1,2-diol is a 2-electron oxidation while you show Mn going from +7 to +4. In the last step of the mechanism have water attack Mn to get the desired +5 Mn. There is a lot of oxidation states of Mn involved but the electrons gained and lost must balance.

Comment: @user55119 If you can detail how the water will need to attack the Mn, I'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your structure in the lower right of your diagram has Mn at +5. Add water to Mn +5 as a "nucleophile" and have glycol oxygen be the leaving group. Just exchanging one oxygen for another.